# Azure DevOps VM Scale Set Deployment in Linux VMs

Tags: azure, shell, deployment, devops, azure-vm-scale-set

I am trying to deploy in **Azure Vm Scale Set** using **Run Custom Script VM extension on VM scale set** in Azure DevOps Release Pipleine. I've a shell script which executes post deployment tasks.

In release pipeline I am using a storage account to archive artifacts and also unchecked the **Skip Archiving custom scripts**. In VMSS deployment task I am getting the following error:

```
2020-03-06T22:59:44.7864691Z ##[error]Failed to install VM custom script extension on VMSS. 
Error: VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'AzureVmssDeploymentTask'. 
Error message: "Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=126

[stdout]

extracting archive cs.tar.gz
Invoking command: ./"main.sh"

[stderr]

./customScriptInvoker.sh: line 12: ./main.sh: Permission denied
```

I found the **customScriptInvoker.sh** under **/var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/1** directory in scale set vm

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
   mkdir a
   echo "extracting archive $1"
   tar -xzC ./a -f $1
   cd ./a
fi

command=$2" "$3
echo $command
echo "Invoking command: "$command

eval $command
```

What should be the way around of this issue?

Comment: You can try run the command with sudo permission in the shell script.

Comment: @David_001 You need to ask a new question with your certain messages.

Answer (score 2):

it seems like a shell execute permission is missing

I am assuming you are running the bash script from the same folder
I would try

```
chmod +rx main.sh
```

you can verify permissions

```
ls -l main.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you also post the ownership of the `main.sh` and `customScriptInvoker.sh` using

```
ls -la main.sh
ls -la customScriptInvoker.sh
```

Check if they are owned by different accounts that may not be in the same group.  If that is the case, you would also get a permission denied error when trying to execute the main.sh script from inside other script.  If that is the case, you can use the `chgrp` command to change the main.sh file to be owned by the same group as the other file.  You can also use `chown` to change the ownership of the main.sh file to be have the same ownership as the other file.  Its hard to tell without seeing the permissions and ownership of the files.